Issues with Tailwind CSS Initialization in Laravel Project
I'm trying to set up Tailwind CSS in my Laravel project following the official Tailwind CSS documentation, but I'm encountering an issue when running the npx tailwindcss init -p command.
After I installed the required npm packages by running:
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer

After that my package.json looks like this:
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
        "axios": "^1.6.4",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.38",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4",
        "vite": "^5.0"
    }
}

However, when I run npx tailwindcss init -p, I get the following error:
'Intermediate\job-board\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1051
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\New Folder\Programming\Laravel\from the courses\tailwindcss\lib\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.8.1

Things I've tried:

Reinstalling dependencies after deleting node_modules and package-lock.json. According to this answer.
Clearing the npm cache:
npm cache clean --force


When I created the Laravel project, I created with --prefer-dist flag. So, try creating the Laravel project without the --prefer-dist flag.

None of these steps resolved the issue. Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?
Additional Details:

Node.js version: v20.8.1
npm version: 10.8.1
Operating System: Windows 11

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Probably the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78024937/the-npx-tailwindcss-command-is-not-working-it-showing-error-module-not-found
